# Near real time data visualization on Apache zeppelin

Tags: hadoop, data-visualization, apache-zeppelin

I am working on Apache zeppelin for data visualization, I am able to visualize data from different sources such as HAWQ.

Now the requirement is to visualize data on a near real time basis for e.g. I need to visualize a table in HAWQ for every 15 seconds. I don't see such feature in a zeppelin. If anyone has done such kind of use cases on zeppelin please share some pointers

Comment: Well I am able to find a cron tab at a header level of zeppelin notebook, which allows me to schedule reports for configured interval.

Comment: cron tab of zeppelin only allows minimum 1 min time interval.. how to achieve 15 sec interval ?